# Using the merge() function in R is there a way to create a indicator column that indicates which row had a match and which did not?

Tags: r, merge

I have this script for now which works and does the merge properly. I would like an extra column that basically goes by row and indicates if the join was executed.

```
df1<-merge(x = df1,y = df2 ,by = "Same_Col",all.x = TRUE,all.y = FALSE)
```

Comment: May be create a row index before doing the `merge` `merge(x = transform(df1, rn = 1:nrow(df1)), y =df2, by = "Same_Col",all.x = TRUE,all.y = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

We can create a sequence of row index before doing the `merge`

```
merge(x = transform(df1, rn = seq_len(nrow(df1))),
      y = df2, by = "Same_Col", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Comment: What am I missing? How is this different than adding the row index after the `merge`?

Comment: @d.b It all depends on whether there are duplicates for the `by` column.  Otherwise, adding after the merge or even for identification `which(!is.na(..` would give the position of non-NA